# Open a PDF from within Preview in another Application using Services

Tags: macos, mac, services, preview, automator

I've started using [Papers](http://mekentosj.com/papers/) for organizing my pdfs. All I'd like to do is to add a Service that I can access from Preview that will automatically open the pdf in Papers. From there, I'll either read it, import it, or what ever else.

My simple attempt is the following:

[image: My attempt at the Service]

I assume it would take a PDF file open in Preview and launch Papers and *maybe* open the PDF in it. The problem is that the service doesn't appear in Preview's Service menu. It does appear in the Preference Pane for Keyboard Shortcuts, so what gives? If there isn't an easy solution, I should be able to do this in an AppleScript.

Comment: The reason this came up was because I'm a dock-nazi; it remains as empty as possible and when papers wasn't opened I wanted to shorten by a click or two getting the dock icon there. The solution is just to keep Papers in the dock. If you make your comment an answer you'll get the best answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough question. First, instead of choosing PDF files, I tried with no input. This is because there aren't any selected files in Preview (which is why you weren't seeing it in the menu). I was able to launch Papers, but this action did not open the current PDF in Papers. Automator has no way of selecting the current PDF in Preview. Also, it appears that AppleScript has been disabled for Preview in favor of Automator. I never thought of this method. I usually just drag the icon from the top of the Preview window onto the Papers icon in the dock.

Maybe someday someone will make a hack that will be better than this answer.